# ¿Es normal que solo me salga esto en Git?

Tags: git

Estoy realizando los preparativos para iniciar un curso de programación web y unos de los pasos previos era la instalación de Git.

En mi ordenador Windows todo normal, y la instalación fue correcta, pero a la hora de hacer la instalación en mi MacBook al principio todo era igual, pero de repente, al establecer un nombre se redujo mucho la información y tras trastear un poco he logrado que vuelva a aparecer el `init.defaultbranch` y establecerla en `main` pero no sé si es normal que me salga tan poca cosa, adjunto captura.

[image: captura de terminal]

Comment: No le veo nada de malo **excepto** que le falta `user.email` en la configuración global.

Comment: Extendiendo el comentario, si tienes configuraciones diferentes entre equipos/repos en los que trabajas en los mismos proyectos, tendrías que verificar que esas diferencias sean intencionales y el efecto sobre los proyectos. Lee la salida de `git help config` para los detalles de cada valor.... Si hay diferencias en cosas como la forma en la que git va a manejar el salto de línea en los archivos, podrías tener un futuro un tanto agitado sin intención